# How do you want it sent? vs. How do you want it send?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Ryan: I have some mail.Can you take care of it for me?

Nathan: Sure. How do you want it sent?

Why in the above text there is "sent"  not "send"?

Comment: It's a kind of passive clause, *concealed passive*, which is not explicitly marked by *BE*. The sentence is equivalent to "How do you want it **to be sent**"?

Comment: @user178049 A good comment that would be a better answer!